# Failed to connect to SQLEXPRESS - Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database

I am trying to connect to my MS SQL database via node.js (Express), but the connection cannot be established. I have probably wrong configuration, but I have tried everything and nothing worked. I also enabled TCP/IP in configuration Manager.

Here is my JS code: https://snipboard.io/ufk49d.jpg
Here is one of my errors: https://snipboard.io/wyTbLi.jpg

When I add localhost or IP adress before SQLEXPRESS in server configuration, it thow this error: https://snipboard.io/RE6Xov.jpg

And also, I added new user and allow SQL auth and windows auth connection.

Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put your machine name in server parameter?

```
 server: 'YOUR_MACHINE_NAME\\SQLEXPRESS',
```

Comment: It works... Thanks a lot. Wierd thing is, that I have tried this, but I probalby missed backslashes..